# Caption inside figure float

Tags: floats, captions

I would like to expect the below output in my LaTeX.

[image]

The `figure` caption should be place in the bottom of the `figure`. The text should be `plurred` with `opacity`. How do achieve this?

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{overlay}{\gdef\capoverlay{#1#2#3\par}}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{overlay}{format=overlay}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{Many of the simple rexpressions in algebra can be thought of     interms of the areas of rectangles.}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest the following:

[image]

This is realized using the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{overlay}{\gdef\capoverlay{#1#2#3\par}}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{overlay}{format=overlay}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  caption color/.store in=\captioncolor,
  caption color=white}

\newcommand{\mygraphics}[3][]{%
  \tcbincludegraphics[float*,every float=\centering,blanker,finish={%
    \captionsetup{skip=0pt}%
    \tcbsetmacrotowidthofnode\mywidth{interior}%
    \node[above,fill=\captioncolor,fill opacity=0.5,text opacity=1,
      outer sep=0mm,inner sep=2mm,text width=\mywidth-4mm]
      at (interior.south) {\captionof{figure}{#3}};},
    #1]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\mygraphics[caption color=blue!50]{Wing.png}
  {Many of the simple expressions in algebra can be thought of
   in terms of the areas of rectangles.}

\mygraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-a}
  {Many of the simple expressions in algebra can be thought of
   in terms of the areas of rectangles.}

\end{document}
```

I made a macro `\mygraphics` which takes two mandatory parameters: the name of the image file and the caption text. Further, a key list can be given as optional parameter. The keys can be any `tcolorbox` keys. The image is made a `float*` as was given by the OP.

In this application, the following options are especially interesting:

- `width` to set the width of the image (shown in the example code). The default is the complete text width.
- `caption color` to set the background color of the caption (show in the example code). The default is white.
- `floatplacement` to set the float options like `htb` etc.

**Update:**

To scale the figure according to the *natural size* of included image, the `hbox` option can be added. But, many pictures may become larger than the textwidth. However, to give options to the underlying `\includegraphics` macro, you can use `graphics options` if needed.

The following code has the `hbox` option set as default. Also, the second example shows how to put a `scale=0.5` option to a picture:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{overlay}{\gdef\capoverlay{#1#2#3\par}}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{overlay}{format=overlay}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  caption color/.store in=\captioncolor,
  caption color=white}

\newcommand{\mygraphics}[3][]{%
  \tcbincludegraphics[float*,every float=\centering,blanker,
    hbox,% <--- the width is determined by the underlying '\includegraphics'
    finish={%
    \captionsetup{skip=0pt}%
    \tcbsetmacrotowidthofnode\mywidth{interior}%
    \node[above,fill=\captioncolor,fill opacity=0.5,text opacity=1,
      outer sep=0mm,inner sep=2mm,text width=\mywidth-4mm]
      at (interior.south) {\captionof{figure}{#3}};},
    #1]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\mygraphics[caption color=blue!50]{Wing.png}
  {Many of the simple expressions in algebra can be thought of
   in terms of the areas of rectangles.}

\mygraphics[graphics options={scale=0.5}]{example-image-a}
  {Many of the simple expressions in algebra can be thought of
   in terms of the areas of rectangles.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to change the `width` should be exact figure size instead of `textwidth`.

Comment: @Balaji If you add the option `hbox`, the figure is sized to the 'natural' size of the included image (like using `\includegraphics` directly without options).

Comment: Where to add the `hbox` command. Could you please update in the answer, please.

Comment: @Balaji See my updated answer.

Comment: When using inside `figure` its showing error. Please refer <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226451/figure-caption-inside-float-with-float?noredirect=1#comment532811_226451> and suggest how to fix it.