# Figure caption inside a tinted box

Tags: floats, formatting, captions

I would like to print the `figure caption` with a "tinted box" (a box with a background colour). How to achieve this?

My MWE is :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphics}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{overlay}{\gdef\capoverlay{#1#2#3\par}}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{overlay}{format=overlay}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
  \begin{figure*}[!h]
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption{How many factors are there in a set of 12?}
  \end{figure*}    
 \lipsum[2]      
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an option using the packages

- [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)
- [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption)
- [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow)

The caption (with multi-line support) width will automatically adjust to the figure width.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{captionbgcolor}{RGB}{103,143,150}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{tcbcaption}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    colback=captionbgcolor,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colupper=white,
    fontupper=\large\sffamily,
    boxsep=0pt
  ]
  #1#2#3
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}
\captionsetup{format=tcbcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
  {\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{eggs}}
  {\caption{how many factors are there in a set of 12?}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Update

According to comments, all images should have constant width, so simply add to the preamble

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.7\textwidth}
```

changing `0.7\textwidth` to the desired value. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example to have a visual guideline

\definecolor{captionbgcolor}{RGB}{103,143,150}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{tcbcaption}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    nobeforeafter,
    colback=captionbgcolor,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colupper=white,
    fontupper=\large\sffamily,
    boxsep=0pt
  ]
  #1#2#3
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}
\captionsetup{format=tcbcaption}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.7\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
  {\includegraphics{eggs}}
  {\caption{how many factors are there in a set of 12?}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
  {\includegraphics{mushrooms}}
  {\caption{how many factors are there in a set of 12?}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And, of course, since the power of `tcolorbox` is used, you can have fancy backgrounds in your captions (I also suppressed the head for the captions using `labelformat=empty`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example

\definecolor{captionbgcolor}{RGB}{103,143,150}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{tcbcaption}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    nobeforeafter,
    enhanced,
    colback=white,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colupper=white,
    fontupper=\large\sffamily,
    boxsep=0pt,
    watermark opacity=1,
    watermark graphics=lichtspiel.jpg,
    watermark overzoom=1.0
  ]
  #1#2#3
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}
\captionsetup{format=tcbcaption,labelformat=empty}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.7\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
  {\includegraphics{eggs}}
  {\caption{how many factors are there in a set of 12?}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
  {\includegraphics{mushrooms}}
  {\caption{how many factors are there in a set of 12?}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Without manual type width=.8\linewidth how to do automatically? Because i have more than 100 figures in my document.

Comment: @Balaji Will all your figures use the same width?

Comment: @Balaji: Gonzalo's `width` setting is specific to the figure, and `\FBwidth` will change accordingly. Please tell us how you include your images. Give us some specific examples and some general rules that you use. Currently the problem is just getting more confusing...

Comment: @Balaji please see my updated answer providing an automatic width for all figures; the caption will adjust automatically too to this width.

Comment: @Gonzalo: It's possible to use `renewcommand` in `tcolorbox`. Because i don't want `Figure~\thefigure` in the caption.

Comment: @Balaji Sure! Add `labelformat=empty` to `\captionsetup`, as in `\captionsetup{format=tcbcaption,labelformat=empty}`

Comment: Brilliant Gonzalo. This output i need.

Comment: @Gonzalo: I have tried and unable to get it. How it's possible to set in single environment like `\tintcaption{{figname.eps}{fig caption}}`.

Comment: @Balaji since this is not directly related to the original question and that the idea here is one question per post. I think the best thing to do would be to open a [`follow-up question`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: When compiling separately your code is working fine and when `sidebyside` it's showing error. Please look <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226614/figure-with-figure-caption-showing-outer-par-mode-error> and suggest how to get the result.

Answer (score 4):

The following assumes you won't have multi-line captions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,xcolor,caption}

\newcommand{\captionbackgroundcolor}[1]{\colorlet{cpbgcol}{#1}}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\captionbackgroundcolor{black!50}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{overlay}{\colorbox{cpbgcol}{#1#2#3}}
\captionsetup{format=overlay,font=white}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{How many factors are there in a set of 12?}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Adjustments to the background colour may be made using `\captionbackgroundcolor{<colour>}`.

---

For multi-line support, you can rely on [`varwidth`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,xcolor,caption,varwidth}

\newcommand{\captionbackgroundcolor}[1]{\colorlet{cpbgcol}{#1}}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\captionbackgroundcolor{black!50}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{overlay}{\colorbox{cpbgcol}{\centering%
  \begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\captionwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
    #1#2#3
  \end{varwidth}}}
\captionsetup{format=overlay,font=white}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image}
  \setlength{\captionwidth}{0.7\textwidth}%
  \caption{How many factors are there in a set of 12?
           How many factors are there in a set of 12?
           How many factors are there in a set of 12?}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

There is no relationship between the `width` key of `\includegraphics` and the `width` key of `\captionsetup`. Even if they were tied, some people don't use `\includegraphics[width=..]` but rather `\includegraphics[height=..]` or `scale` to adjust the inherent width of an included image. As such, I'd suggest manually setting `\captionwidth` to match your image output.

---

Of course, the above statement holds for the packages or interfaces used. [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) is an alternative that captures the requirements in a single package - both the caption and the width-of-image requests.

Comment: The `caption` width should match with `figure` width. How do control this and `multiline` caption is not breaking and how do break automatically.

Comment: @Balaji: See the updated answer.

Comment: Without manual type `width=0.7\textwidth` how to do automatically? Because i have more than `100 figures` in my document.

Comment: @Balaji: Do you have all the figures at some fixed width? Do they vary in terms of their width? Should *all* figures adhere to this requirement?

Comment: All the figures are not fixed width. It's different width. Yes that's my requirements and how to fix it?

Comment: @Balaji: I assume therefore that you just want to change something globally, which will allow you make *all* figures match the width of the included image. That is, you don't want to change the interface. You just want to sit back, relax, and let everything happen by itself? If that's the case, then one may have to understand what the generic layout of your `figure` environment looks like. One can capture the content and reprocess it in a number of ways, but you should provide the community with some generic rules as to how you specify the code inside your `figure`.