# Caption without background color in LaTeX with mdframed

Tags: captions, mdframed

I am trying to get the figure environment renewed using mdframed to get every figure with a grey background. However, the caption should not have this grey background.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{mdframed}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

\let\originalfigure=\figure
\let\endoriginalfigure=\endfigure

\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{
\begin{originalfigure}[#1]
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=black!30,backgroundcolor=black!4]
}{
\end{mdframed}
\end{originalfigure}
} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Renger

Answer (score 1):

According to the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226566), the question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{mdframed}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

\usepackage{graphicx,caption}

\let\originalfigure=\figure
\let\endoriginalfigure=\endfigure

\renewenvironment{figure}[2][]{
\begin{originalfigure}[#1]
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=black!30,backgroundcolor=black!4]
}{
\end{mdframed}
\end{originalfigure}
} 

\newcommand{\captionbackgroundcolor}[2]{\colorlet{cpbgcol}{#1}}
\DeclareCaptionFont{black}{\color{black}}
\captionbackgroundcolor{white}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{overlay}{\colorbox{cpbgcol}{#1#2#3}}
\captionsetup{format=overlay,font=black}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image} 
\caption{Test long text!}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I propose another approach: nesting `\includegraphics` in an `\fcolorbox`.  Here are two variants, one with a variable width (depending on the image width) and another with \linewidth width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\bgincludegraphics}[1]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}\fcolorbox{IndianRed}{PapayaWhip!20!}{\qquad\includegraphics{#1}\qquad}}

\newcommand{\bkgincludegraphics}[1]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}\fcolorbox{IndianRed}{PapayaWhip!20!}{%
\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]{\includegraphics{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\bgincludegraphics{example-image}
\caption{Test1}
\bigskip

\bkgincludegraphics{example-image}
\caption{Test2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]